# trustless and auto-executed agreements

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

So, I am very new to the smart contracts ecosystem.  I watched this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ).  From what I gathered the major selling points of smart contracts are the trustless or trust minized, and auto-executed agreements, etc.

At `19:35-21:10`, The author brought up an example of insurance company.  "..they are the ones who decides whether or not they're going to execute their agreement..."

So, in a smart contracts ecosystem, the insurance company will have a smart contract written in such a way that when a claimant files a claim it will automatically funds the claim without adjuster or any human intervention?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, in a smart contracts ecosystem, the insurance company will have a smart contract written in such a way that when a claimant files a claim it will automatically funds the claim without adjuster or any human intervention?

This is not true.

An insurance company must evaluate any claim off-chain, with whatever proprietary rules and committees they have in place for accepting claims.

Please do not believe everything you see and hear on Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Smart contract code is executed as reaction to a transaction (read+write) or a call (read only), and they cannot be executed without an action.

The transaction can possibly originate from anyone. Not just the insurance company or the claimer, but also some automated sender script.

Having said that, then it depends on each specific smart contract implementation whether it accepts transaction from other senders than some authorized address, and how exactly it reacts.

For example it may just check that the claim is valid and hasn't been paid out yet, and then send the payout to a predefined insuree address - no matter who executes the function.... But it may also allow to process the claim only if the function is executed by the insurance company. Depends on the specific implementation.